# Passing Data from one Form to another Form in Windows Form c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms  form1 and form2:

1. `Form1` named "DemandePrixClient" is made from `Textboxes` and `Comboboxs` and `button` Transfer.
2. `Form2` named "DemandePrixFournisseur" is made from `Textboxes`(to pass all the data entries)

When I click to `button` Transfer, This will show up `form2` and all the Inputs of `Form1`.

Thanks in Advance.

I have the code below but it doesn't work.

```
//Code Form1
public partial class DemandePrixClient : Form
{
    public string textbox1;
    public string textbox2;
    public string textbox3;
    public string textbox5;
    public string combobox1;
    public string combobox2;
    public string combobox4;
    public string combobox6;
    public string datetime;

    public DemandePrixClient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void DemandePrixClient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: cette ligne de code charge les données dans la table 'timarDataSet1.Client'. Vous pouvez la déplacer ou la supprimer selon vos besoins.
        this.clientTableAdapter.Fill(this.timarDataSet1.Client);

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DemandePrixClient info = new DemandePrixClient();
        info.textBox1 = textBox1;
        info.textBox2 = textBox2;
        info.textbox3 = textbox3;
        info.textbox5 = textbox5;
        info.comboBox1 = comboBox1;
        info.combobox2 = combobox2;
        info.comboBox4 = comboBox4;
        info.comboBox5 = comboBox5;
        info.datetime = datetime;
        DemandePrixFournisseur dpf = new DemandePrixFournisseur(info);
        dpf.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

//Code Form2

```
public partial class DemandePrixFournisseur : Form
{

    private DemandePrixClient info;

    public DemandePrixFournisseur(DemandePrixClient information)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        info = information;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `DemandePrixFournisseur` from  `DemandePrixClient` using present instance `this` keyword

```
public string text1;
public string text2;
public string text3;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.text1 = this.textBox1.Text;
        this.text2 = this.textBox2.Text;
        this.text3 = this.textBox3.Text;
        DemandePrixFournisseur dpf = new DemandePrixFournisseur(this);
        dpf.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

then you can get all value

```
public partial class DemandePrixFournisseur : Form
{

    private DemandePrixClient info;

    public DemandePrixFournisseur(DemandePrixClient information)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        info = information;
        this.textBox1.Text = info.text1; // you can get other value like this way
        this.textBox2.Text = info.text2;
        this.textBox3.Text = info.text3;  
        //or simply
        this.textBox2.Text = information.text2;
        // and others textbox and combobox value similarly
    }


}
```

Comment: When I write `this.textBox1.Text = info.textBox1.Text` it underligne it , I t's false

Comment: what do you mean by underlined ? did you try my latest edit ?

Comment: `this.textBox1.Text = info.textBox1.Text` , it underligne `Text` (it can't found it)

Comment: do you have any textbox named `textBox1` in form `DemandePrixFournisseur` ?

Comment: of course , I have, It underligne The second **Text** but when I write  `this.textBox1.Text = info.textBox1`, it know it

Comment: ok got it where is the problem, the textbox is private so add some public variable like you added in your code, I have updated my code, see this

Comment: It doesn't work , The textboxes of `Form2` are all empty

Comment: but works here, do you have used `this` before all variable I have used ?

Comment: I've update my code now .Thanks ,it works

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to achieve this by  class static fields.On your Form1 set data in static fields and on your Form2 get data from static fields.